# Wake tablet-pc from sleep by start button

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep, wake-up

I have a lenovo yoga2 tablet that runs with windows 8.1.

The power button of my tablet is not working and I want to wake my tablet from sleep by pressing the start button.

Is there any way to do this?